# What are recommended design pattern for solr in production with security

Tags: php, solr, proxy, lucene, network-security

I am using solr 4.10.3. It is in cloud mode with one shard and three nodes ( one leader and two slave). I have to bring it in production. My website is in ajax/php that requires to communicate with solr. I am concerned about security.

1. Should Solr and webserver on same systems or not ?. Should I place them on seprate VMs ?
2. Is it good to give solr direct access to open internet ? if not should I used proxy ?
3. If I have to use proxy, then is it good to create three VMs, one contains web-server, second solr and third proxy ?

Answer (score 2):

Solr is not well-suited to be public facing ([although some progress has been made](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Authentication+and+Authorization+Plugins)), so I would strongly recommend having it unavailable to the Internet as a whole, and write a small middleware in your application that takes the request from the client application (where you make the AJAX call), validates it and passes it on to the correct endpoint in Solr.

That will make it harder to overload your server with bogus queries that uses other modules of Solr that you didn't think of (such as document clustering, which can be very resource intensive), and will shut down any access to the update, import or backup endpoints.

The middleware (which I guess would be written in PHP for you) would just take the query, make sure it seems OK, escape it and pass it on to Solr before returning the result to the user.